# VSCode if indentation when leaving out curly braces

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, indentation

In VSCode, when writing javascript/typescript I often write ifs without curly braces. Especially for early exits.

```
foo() {
  ...
  if(...) 
     return;
  ...
  for(...) {
    ...
    if(...)
      continue;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

In VSCode, the return/continue/whatever I put on the new line does not get indented. Is there any setting for this?

I only have icons and Debugger for Chrome extensions.

This is the way VSCode formats it:

[image]

It actually turns out this is not the only weird indentation going on!

This looks ok:

[image]

However, if I put the args on different lines. (may be required for long variable names):

[image]

The rest of that function ends up indented, and so does the rest of the file.

I've tried to reinstall VSCode, does not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So someone just gave me a weird -1 with the motivation "This question does not show any research effort; it's unclear and and not useful" which I don't understand.

1. I have searched SO and the VS git forum. Found nothing, that is why I asked here. There are other similar questions but all I could find are about actual placements of the curly braces. 

2. Unclear, how? I want to know how to get indentation without curly braces. How is that not obvious?

3. Not useful, why? Well for everyone in the same situation as me it is.

Comment: I don't see any downvotes or close votes. In fact I upvoted your question because I think it's a very worthwhile question - even if my answer (explained more fully below) is "don't do this!" :-)

Comment: Thx. There was a -1 a while back :)

Comment: Do you have prettier or eslint extension installed?  The indentation works fine for me for your use cases, I don't use prettier.

Comment: Nope, see edit.

Answer (score 3):

This won't answer your question about how to get VS Code to do what you want, but if I may offer some advice: leaving out the curly braces can be dangerous. It led to a major security flaw in Apple's implementation of SSL: the infamous [goto fail](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) bug.

Here's the code where they ran into trouble:

```
if ((err = SSLFreeBuffer(&hashCtx)) != 0)
    goto fail;
if ((err = ReadyHash(&SSLHashSHA1, &hashCtx)) != 0)
    goto fail;
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &clientRandom)) != 0)
    goto fail;
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &serverRandom)) != 0)
    goto fail;
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
    goto fail;
    goto fail;
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.final(&hashCtx, &hashOut)) != 0)
    goto fail;
```

See the problem?

Curly braces are not a *perfect* protection against bugs like this, but they certainly help. You're much less likely to have your own `goto fail` bug when you use them.

Some developers, myself included, feel that it's OK to omit the curly braces *only* when you write the `if` statement as a one-liner. If you're simply doing an early exit from a function, this is fine:

```
if( ... ) return;
```

You're much less likely to create a `goto fail` bug when it's on a single line. But the moment you split it into two lines, the curly braces are required:

```
if( ... ) {
    return;
}
```

or:

```
if( ... ) {
    console.log( 'debug message' );
    return;
}
```

Let's try that without the curly braces. First we have:

```
if( ... )
    return;
```

No worries, this code works as expected. Now let's add the debug message:

```
if( ... )
    console.log( 'debug message' );
    return;
```

Oops!

Since you're putting the open curly brace on the same line as the `if` statement already (which I completely agree with), it only costs you one extra line to add the closing curly brace. Either make your early returns one-liners, or use the curly braces. This will avoid the risk of an eventual `goto fail` bug of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get your point, but I am not looking for suggestions on coding style. I prefer to code this way and I have never ever in 20+ years of coding made that mistake. Editors with working auto indentation simply makes that more or less impossible. I want to avoid the curly braces because I think they makes the code harder to read and and I don't like inline return/continue as they can end up way out to the right in the file.

Comment: Roger that, and thanks for not being offended by my advice. :-) Alas, I don't have any ideas on how to get VS Code to do what you want.

Comment: Np, hopefully someone does :)

Comment: The problem is the formatting, if only first line after the `if` was indented, and anything else was at the same level as `if`, than it wouldn't be an issue. Current VSCode implementation indent line based on previous line, regardless of the syntax.